# Generators for the ideal corresponding to four points

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider the set $\{(0,0),(1,1),(2,2),(1,0)\}$, I'm trying to find the generators for its ideal. I know that $V(F\cup G) = V(FG)$, also notice that three points are colinear, so I can write it as $$V(x-y, x(x-1)(x-2))\cup V(x-1,y)$$ and then $$V( x^2 -x -xy+y, x^4-4x^3 + 5 x^2 - 2x  ,xy-y^2, x^3y - 3x^2y +2 xy )$$.

From then on, how could I simplify it? Is this the final answer?

Any hint or suggestion are welcome.